# How to remove the last 2 characters of every element in a column of a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (df) and in the last column, all of the elements are showing up as

> 1055.0000.0

so the last 2 characters are always ".0". Whats the most efficient way to do this? the last columns name is always different so im not sure how to approach this. I have tried to loop over the pandas df but it takes too much memory and breaks the code. is there a way to do something like

df[ last column ] = df[ last column - last 2 characters]

or make a new df then append it in?

Answer (score 3):

Vectorized operations are almost always faster. `.str` method allows pandas to vectorize strings

```
df["last_col"].str[:-2]
```

Can time it using `%%timeit` magic command in jupyter notebook.

```
%%timeit
df.iloc[:, -1].str[-2:]
>>> 352 µs ± 4.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
df["last_col"].str[:-2]
>>> 242 µs ± 4.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `str` accessor:

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].astype(str).str[-2:].astype(int)
```

Comment: This is very efficient thank you. How would you then go about making all the elements of the column into integers?

Comment: Very good thank you. One last thing, I am getting an error saying "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas", I am assuming this means that the input eg 1055.0000.0 is not recognised as a string? how would I change the whole column beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `rsplit`:

```
s = '105.0000.0'
s.rsplit('.0', 1)[0]
```

output:

```
105.0000
```